# PHP mail(): PDF won't be decoded from Base64

Tags: php, pdf, base64

I'm working on building a mailing script in PHP. I have this code:

```
$mime_boundary = "---".md5(time());

$message = 'Content-Type: application/pdf;name="datenschutz.pdf";charset=utf-8\n';
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";

$fileContents = file_get_contents("/datenschutz.pdf");

$message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($fileContents)) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--$mime_boundary--";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I'm aware that PHPMailer exists, alongside other libraries which would make this easier, but the problem is that I want to sell this software eventually and host it on different servers, so installing a library every time wouldn't be optimal. Therefore, I want to mostly use built-in PHP features.

I do recieve the email, and there is a PDF file attached to it, but neither Browsers nor Adobe Reader can open it.

I personally believe that it is because of the Base64 encoding, since I decoded the file once on a webpage and it worked just fine.

How Am I able to tell the Email program/Adobe Reader to decode the file from base64?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** I replaced all different linebreaks with `\n\n` and redesigned the Content-Type strings so that they are strings with double-quotes. Sadly, it still does not work.

Comment: _“I want to sell this software eventually”_ - all the _more_ reason to use a proper mailer library, instead of brewing your own little mail soup.

Comment: You've got to be consistent with spaces and returns when you make your own mailer. I see `\n`, `\n\n` and `\r\n\r\n`. This is hardly consistent. These things matter, maybe not to all mail clients, but many.

Comment: Oh, worse, the first `\n` is in a string with single quotes, that means these literal characters will be used in the email.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. I don't really understand what the difference between single quotes and double quotes.